# Cost function for linear regression with multiple variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, linear-regression

The multivariate linear regression cost function:

[image]

Is the following code in Matlab correct?

```
function J = computeCostMulti(X, y, theta)
    m = length(y);
    J = 0;
    J=(1/(2*m)*(X*theta-y)'*(X*theta-y);
end
```

Comment: What about testing it with some example data? There is an obvious difference, you use theta while the function uses h_theta, but this might be just an issue of variable names.

Comment: Nope, not right. The most steps are already prefilled for you here http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/DocumentPage.php?course=MachineLearning&doc=exercises/ex3/ex3.html

Comment: It looks fine to me, provided `y` is a column vector.  Although you have an extra `(` in there and the `J=0;` is unecessary. If @madbitloman sees a mistake, maybe they can point it out.

Comment: It looks fine, but you need an extra bracket surrounding the `1/(2*m)` term, so `J=(1/(2*m))*(X*theta-y)'*(X*theta-y);`.  Other than that, what you have there works.  BTW, that's probably from Andrew Ng's Machine Learning course... judging from the function definition and the cost function itself.

Comment: @madbitloman - Why is it not right?  What the OP is trying to implement is essentially the last equation on the page you linked: http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/courses/MachineLearning/exercises/ex3/img13.png ... and it's fine, provided that there is an additional bracket inserted near the beginning.

Comment: @rayryeng sorry, I meant bracket as well. Also it seems like he wants to iterate in the same manner as in the link and I do suspect output should be an array rather than just a single updated value

Comment: @madbitloman - No, it's simply the cost given the parameters and current input.... but good job in looking into it more than you should.  It isn't our job to do this kind of stuff.  If you analyze the equation carefully, `X*theta - y` would produce a column vector, and so the multiplication (`(X*theta-y)'*(X*theta-y)`) is actually a dot product.

Answer (score 2):

Your are missing a `)` in the end:

```
J=(1/(2*m))*(X*theta-y)'*(X*theta-y);
          ^
```

Answer (score 2):

There is two ways i tried which is essentially the same code.

```
    J = (X * theta - y)'*(X * theta - y)/2*m;
```

or you can try:

```
    J = (1/(2*m))*(X * theta - y)'*(X * theta - y)
```